# How to find a computer running a specific script on a local area network

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, lan

My setup is that I have a machine running little eclipse server in node, and I want to configure other machines on the LAN to run a website off of that first computer. Everything is working fine, but I have to manually tell the other computers which local IP address to use when opening chrome.

All computers at this point are running ubuntu.

Ideally I'd like to make a bash script on any new computer which finds the IP address of the computer running the express server, then opens chrome at that address.

Googling tends to get me answers for the question 'how to see all computers on my LAN'. It seems that I can achieve that in many ways, most notably `nmap`.

NMap works fine, but now my question is how I can make the server computer broadcast its status as the desired machine, then extract its sepcific IP address?

Some of the other possibilities I've considered are the following (I state why I'm not sure they're right for me, but please correct me if I'm wrong):

**Hosts File**

This requires setup for each collection of computers, which is undesirable

**DHCP+DNS on router**

Again requires set up on the router, which can't be guaranteed to have the required functionality every time.

**DNS server on a machine**

Again this requires knowing the IP address of the server

What I'd really like is for the process to be automatic – the server machine is happily running its local website, then any other computer that joins the network is able to find it then open that website in chrome, without the person installing the computer having to know the server's IP address. Is such a thing feasible?

Comment: Use arp-scan to retrieve all ip from your local network, then loop over those ip with nmap "sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet" where eth0 s the device on which you are connected (ifconfig)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But that looks like code to find the address of the computer I’m connecting from. What I’m looking for is code for the computer in connecting from to find the other computer on the lan that is running a specific script.